# Adding VPI to project with a lot of dependencies causes error on pre-3.0 devices 

Tags: android, intellij-idea, actionbarsherlock, roboguice, viewpagerindicator

I recently switched from eclipse to intellij, it has been a great experience so far I am really loving it. However, I have run into a strange issue that I have been hitting my head against the wall with. I am trying to use ViewPagerIndicator, ActionBarSherlock, RoboSherlock, and RoboGuice as well as some other common frameworks in my application. It all works fine until I add VPI.

Basically, when adding the ViewPagerIndicator dependency to my project it breaks the application for pre 3.0 devices (runs fine on 3.0+).

The error is rather confusing because it seems to be something wrong with an ABS compatible theme not being picked up when the VPI apklib is present (please note that I am using an ABS compatible theme in my manifest).

```
>09-18 10:33:15.986: ERROR/COM.IRIE.TASTEBUD/ObserverMethodListener.java:34(509): main java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
        at roboguice.event.eventListener.ObserverMethodListener.onEvent(ObserverMethodListener.java:32)
        at roboguice.event.EventManager.fire(EventManager.java:130)
        at com.github.rtyley.android.sherlock.roboguice.activity.RoboSherlockActivity.onCreate(RoboSherlockActivity.java:63)
        at com.irie.tastebud.view.activity.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:38)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
```

When I look deeper at the trace I see the below (even though I am using a sherlock theme):

> ```
>    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You must use Theme.Sherlock, Theme.Sherlock.Light, Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar, or a derivative.
>     at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockCompat.generateLayout(ActionBarSherlockCompat.java:1007)
>     at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockCompat.installDecor(ActionBarSherlockCompat.java:919)
>     at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockCompat.setContentView(ActionBarSherlockCompat.java:853)
>     at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity.setContentView(SherlockActivity.java:218)
>     at roboguice.inject.ContentViewListener.optionallySetContentView(ContentViewListener.java:21)
>     ... 19 more**
> ```

See full exception stack trace and activity/manifest/pom.xml code  @ https://gist.github.com/3743646 .

Once again - this only happens on pre-3.0 devices when adding the VPI project as a maven dependency. If I remove VPI - the app runs fine on 2.2+ devices.

My Pom.xml is almost exactly like the Android Bootstrap application which works fine on 2.2+ as far as I know.

My guess is that I have some kind of dependency configuration issue on my end. I am pretty green with maven and intellij so it has been quite difficult to trouble shoot.

I am not sure if anyone else has seen this behavior, or if I am making a rookie mistake. Any help is appreciated - if I solve the issue, I will update this question with the answer.

Thanks to everyone in advance and sorry if I broke any stackoverflow etiquette with this post.

EDIT: Found potential related issue @ http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-90719

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found another workaround for this issue that works much faster. In Android facet config change resource processing from *"Run 'process-resources' Maven task before Make"* to *"Compile resources by IDE"*. See screenshot in attachment. After this change all works fine and **fast** on all android versions

[image: Facet configuration]

Comment: confirmed that this indeed fixes the problem and is much quicker. Thanks for the update!

Answer (score 1):

So instead of using a default android build configuration, I used the android maven plugin and did a mvn android:deploy-dependencies and android:run, and the problem is gone.

Before I was just using the default android build configuration for intellij, which now looking back does not look like it was the right approach considering I am using the android maven plugin to manage my dependencies in the first place.

Hope this helps someone.

P.S. intellij-idea rocks!

Comment: I was tryed to use this workaround too, but unfortunately this solution is tooooooo slow. When u builds your apk with Android build config idea caches many things and build quite fast. But when u using maven build for this it always rebuilds and re-package all your sources, what makes this builds very slow. Because of these problems, I was forced to avoid using VPI lib in my project